# Add items in URL without page reload (pushState)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, pushstate

I have a function that adds items in my URL without page reloading.
I use this in a filter function. Every time some one clicks an item in the filter, this function will add the clicked item in the URL.
If you click the same item again, the item will disappear again.

```
function childboxes(MainElement, ChildElement){
    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
    var extra = pathArray[2];       
    var clicked = "&"+MainElement+'='+ChildElement;
    var re = new RegExp(clicked, 'g');       

    if(extra.match(re)){   
        //remove item from URL        
        var extra = extra.replace(clicked, "");
        window.history.replaceState(null, null, extra);

    }else{
        //Add items in URL  
         window.history.pushState(null, null, extra+"&"+MainElement+'='+ChildElement);
    }        
}
```

Example:
http://www.domain.com/en/webshop&brand=18&category=shoes&product=test

And there is my problem, every added item adds this: &brand=18
As we all know, the first parameter has to start with an "?" instead of an "&".

I have no idea how to make sure the first item begins with an question mark.

Using something else then `pushState` and `replaceState` is fine by me. The only thing I want is that the page isn't reloading when we update the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simple check:

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, extra+ ( extra.indexOf("?")>-1 ? "&" : "?" ) +MainElement+'='+ChildElement);
```

**Edit:**

Regexp fixed:

```
var clicked = "[&\\?]"+MainElement+'='+ChildElement;
```

And:

```
var extra = extra.replace(re, ""); // you can replace by regex
```

**Edit2:**

Clean up

```
function childboxes(MainElement, ChildElement){
    var extra = window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
    var regex = new RegExp("[&\\?]"+MainElement+'='+ChildElement, 'g');       

    extra = extra.replace(regex, "");
    extra = extra+ ( extra.indexOf("?") > -1 ? "&" : "?" ) +MainElement+ '=' +ChildElement;
    window.history.pushState(null, null, extra);
}
```

**Edit3:**

replaceState

```
function childboxes(MainElement, ChildElement){
    var extra = window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
    var regex = new RegExp("[&\\?]"+MainElement+'='+ChildElement, 'g');

    var isReplace = extra.match(regex);
    extra = extra.replace(regex, "");
    extra = extra+ ( extra.indexOf("?") > -1 ? "&" : "?" ) +MainElement+ '=' +ChildElement;
    window.history[isReplace?'replaceState':'pushState'](null, null, extra);
}
```

Comment: Works great for the first update. But this is happening now:
http://www.domain.com/en/webshop?brand=18
--new click--
http://www.domain.com/en/webshop?category=shoes

So it works, but it does not add the new clicked items behind the current URL.

Comment: Sorry man :( 
It only updates the same piece. 
That's the same problem I had the whole time.

Comment: `var extra = window.location.pathname + window.location.search;` pathname doesn't include querystring.

Comment: But how would I implement my replaceState in this function? We can use that to remove items if you remove something in your filter.

Comment: Got it :) `function childboxes(MainElement, ChildElement){
    var extra = window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
    var regex = new RegExp("[&\\?]"+MainElement+'='+ChildElement, 'g');    
        
        
    if(extra.match(regex)){  
            var extra = extra.replace(regex, "");
            window.history.replaceState(null, null, extra);
    }else{

    extra = extra.replace(regex, "");
    extra = extra+ ( extra.indexOf("?") > -1 ? "&" : "?" ) +MainElement+ '=' +ChildElement;
    window.history.pushState(null, null, extra);
    }
} `

Comment: I think that you should add `MainElement+'='+ChildElement` in both cases, but if it's working... ;)

Comment: Oh, One more thing If you have `/en/webshop?brand=18&category=shoes` and click `childboxes(brand, 18)` (if it's possible) then url will be broken: `/en/webshop&category=shoes?brand=18`. At least I think that :P